# I want to make a graph with sensing data

Tags: java, arduino, mpandroidchart, data-transfer

I need to make a graph with data which come from arduino.

Data is sended as String and I want to draw graph with parts of the data

For example,

> Arduino sents "1234567890", Graph will be drawn by "12345"

Here is my codes

```
ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> test1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Entry> value1 = new ArrayList<>();

test1.add("123456909090"); 
test1.add("234567909090");
test1.add("334567909090");
test1.add("434567909090");

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

   String a = test1.get(i);

   a.substring(0,6);

   float b = Float.parseFloat(a);

   value1.add(new Entry(i,b));
}

ScatterDataSet set1 = new ScatterDataSet(value1);
```

and there is an exception raised

> FATAL EXCEPTION:java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero

**I have never used devide.**

How can i solve it?

And If there is a better way, let me know.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: On what line does it happen? We would like to know.

Comment: There is a function named setColor, it has a porblem. I deleted this and problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, when you resive data, before use data you should check them with any control mechanism like if ... etc. it will help you. In my limited programming knowledge zero division makes problem ( any number / 0 == is problem) if you have to do this operations I prefer change the value like 0.0001 or 0.000001 or you can't use the data which was sended and wait , while you waiting you can use old data. It depens you and your project....

Comment: I found the problem. It was caused by some function. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Realy sometimes it is the best way to check functions.... I also so happy because you found problem and solve it... = )